# Day and night time calculation in Excel sheet

Tags: excel

In MS Excel sheet I want to calculate the time I work in the day hours i.e. the hours between sunrise and sunset, and any hours after sunset.

An example might be that I start work at 06:00 am and finish at 09:00 pm.
Sunrise is 07:00 am and sunset is 06:30 pm.
The total time worked all day would be 15 hours.
Time worked during the day (between sunrise and sunset) would be 11 hours and 30 minutes.
Time worked at night would be 3 hours and 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I think you want to achieve.
Since I have included sunrise and sunset as columns it means that you can add another column `Date` and then you can track each new day as a new row; since sunrise and sunset change each day you cannot simply have one cell to set the times for these for all your data.

[image: Time table]

The formulas:

- A2
  `06:00:00`
- B2
  `21:00:00`
- C2
  `07:00:00`
- D2
  `18:30:00`
- E2
  `=IF(B2>D2,D2,B2)-IF(A2<C2,C2,A2)`
- F2
  `=(B2-A2)-E2`

Notice that I have written the times in 24 hour clock.
This is important since Excel cannot tell the difference between 07:00 if it is AM or PM and you cannot pass AM or PM in the cells.

The formula in E2 will check if you have started before sunrise or not. If you have started before sunrise then it will just use the sunrise time.
Then it will do the same check for sunset; using sunset if you have worked after sunset.
After that it will just subtract the two numbers and return the time worked.

F2 will just simply subtract the start and end time to work out total time worked all day and will then just subtract the time worked in the day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution :)[image]

Just copy and paste the formulas in E5 and F5 and drag them down to calculate the time as per your requirement

Formula in E5 is:

```
=IF(AND(B5<$C$1;C5>=$G$1);$G$1-$C$1;IF(AND(B5>=$C$1;C5<$G$1);C5-B5;IF(AND(B5<$C$1;C5<$G$1);C5-$C$1;$G$1-B5)))
```

Formula in F5 is:

```
=C5-B5-E5
```

It is important to note that my solution covers all four possibilities which are:
1. Start work at night and end at night
2. Start work at day and end at day
3. Start work at night and end at day
4. Start work at day and end at night 
:)